# Sorting textbox.text alphabetically

Tags: vb.net, string

using VB.net

if textbox1.text = "example"

how would I get textbox2.text to show "aeelmpx"

as that is the alphabetical sequence of letters?

declare it as a string, and then manipulate the string im sure, but im an enthusiastic amateur at best!

Comment: convert to char array, sort, create a new string from the result. the `.Text`, which *is* a string cant be sorted directly

Comment: Still confused? Here are some Links which may help you [ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) , [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfce6bw8.aspx) and [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since String implements IEnumerable(Of Char), you can use code like this:

```
textBox2.Text = New String(textBox1.Text.OrderBy(Function(c) c).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's tried and tested.

```
 Private Shared Sub ConvertToChar(ByRef ctrl As System.Windows.Forms.Control)
    Dim charArray() As Char = String.Empty

    Try
        If TypeOf ctrl Is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Text) Then
                charArray = ctrl.Text.ToCharArray
                Array.Sort(charArray)
                ctrl.Text = charArray
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

**Example Useage**

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ConvertToChar(TextBox1)
 End Sub
```

You can also add to that method for other controls if you would need...

Comment: Can you assign the character array directly back to the .Text property?